# Having multiple Controls using the same CommandBinding in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, commandbinding

In my Window, there are several controls which perform the same action.

For example I have a `MenuItem`

```
<MenuItem x:Name="_mnuNew" Command="New" Header="_New" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N"/>
```

and a `Button`

```
<Button x:Name="_btnNew" Command="New"/>
```

performing the "New" Command

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="New" CanExecute="IsNewExecuteable" Executed="NewExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

The assignment works as desired for the `MenuItem`. Setting the Command for the `Button` results in a **NullReferenceException**

I've read [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/) that Command Bindings do also work on Buttons, so what am I doing wrong.

EDIT:

```
    private void IsNewExecuteable(object sender, System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = IsRunning; //IsRunning is a siple property that is tested and works
    }
```

Comment: it works fine on my end .. is there anything more to it ?

Comment: @LuckyLikey I can only suspect that there is a problem in `NewExecute` (maybe `IsNewExecuteable`). Post exception stack trace at least.

Comment: @dkozl The stacktrace is 8800 characters long.. cannot post it^^ but the top one is *bei System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnCanExecute(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)*

Comment: post code in your can execute ... seems prob there.. command bindings are perfect

Comment: @Muds no that's all, l how can there be a misstake in 'NewExecute' or 'IsNewExecuteable' if the 'MenuItem' - Control can be connected sucesscully?

Comment: that we will decide after looking into can exec.... you said last call was to the top one is bei System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnCanExecute... that means command bindings are fine

Comment: @Muds Ah well.. thanks didn't know that. So i've added the method..

Comment: in that case I can only say its a simple and trivial case of command bindings, I have just replicated your code and it works find at my end, problem is somewhere else imo .. do some debugging and share results

Comment: @Muds Anyway thanks a lot for your help, im looking forward to solve the issue and sharing my solution.

Comment: that's fine :) if you have sm findings do share..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole `CommandBinding` Part was fine but there was a mistake inside of `IsNewExecuteable`, in which I trusted and which was obviously wrong.

Excuse me for Posting this question, everytime I am using a technique new to me I don't see obvious misstakes.

**Anyway thanks a lot to those who helped**